# What iPad app is this?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I was wondering what this app was called that i also saw during an Apple video.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solar Walk](http://vitotechnology.com/solar-walk.html) is the name of the app.